# Redmine retrieving files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, redmine

I have hosted redmine at `http://redmine.pcwallpapergirl.com`

i will tell what exactly i did..

1. Connected to ssh
2. Created a dir for the project (home/account/public_html/somefolder/projectname/)
3. using this commmand i download project from github

   git clone (url)
4. Logged in to redmine.mydomain.com
5. Created a project named transload and in settings>repository i selected SCM git and specified the project absolute path
6. Added Users for the project
7. ??

Now i want to work on that project and want to make changes on those files.. which software i want to use.. trust me i spent more than an 8hour trying to figure out in redmine.. and one more which link i have to give for retrieving files i mean url of the repository

i tried

> http://redmine.mydomain.coom/svn/projectname,
>
> http://redmine.mydomain.coom/projectname/svn

None of them worked ... please correct me what i think is redmine is a project management which we can upload our local files and track all changes we made by date, spent time, diff by using SVN tool like tortoise...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little difficult to understand but I will try to help. I currently use Redmine at my place of employment for various implementations.

You are correct that Redmine can be used as a project management tool and yes you can upload files etc. Personally I think you are better of using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (or similar) as your version control system and just use Redmine for tracking bugs, new features, customer complaints etc. ie create tickets for various projects and your team can collaborate on those tickets.

It is also handy for creating wiki's to support your various projects.

If you really want to use Redmine as an interface to your repository perhaps this can help.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Automate_repository_creation

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_to_handle_SVN_repositories_creation_and_access_control_with_Redmine

Personally I'd recommend using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/). Its great software and widely supported.